# Failed to resolve al compilar librería en android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy tratando de implementar una libreria en android studio 3.2, la cual es:

```
implementation 'com.github.material-components-android:1.0.0'
```

Pero a la hora de compilar el gradle me genera el siguiente error

```
Failed to resolve: com.github.material-components-android:1.0.0:
```

Los archivo de configuración los tengo asi, gradle.app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 27
  defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.alcadio.nodejsmysql"
     minSdkVersion 21
     targetSdkVersion 27
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"
     testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


//RXJava
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'

//Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.3.0'

//Material Edit Text
implementation 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

//Material Dialog
implementation 'com.github.javiersantos:MaterialStyledDialogs:2.1'

//Material Button
implementation 'com.github.material-components-android:1.0.0'
}
```

El gradle del project es:

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'


    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven{ url "https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven/"}
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

No se que podria estar pasando, alguien me podría ayudar con esto

Comment: seguro que no es`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` lo que quieres usar?

Answer (score 0):

Para usar los "Material Components" de Android la forma adecuada de definir la dependencia debe ser:

```
  dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    // ...
  }
```

Revisa su [documentación](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md).